# Cannot rety request after receive 403 in interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am tring to intercept the request that result in 403 (because the token expire) and then perform a request to get a new token to be able to perfom again the request that fails.

But for some reason the next.handle(request) with the new token didn't perform the request that was intercept.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthExpiredInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly router: Router
  ) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
          this._handle403Error(request, next);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  _handle403Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
    this.accountService.getNewToken(refreshToken).then(
      (res) => {
        if (res) {
          request = this._addToken(request, this.authService.getToken());
          return next.handle(request); // Don't perform the request intercepted 
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      }
    );
  }

  _addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        JWT_TOKEN: token,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you forgot return statement.

```js
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 403) {
          return this._handle403Error(request, next);
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

_handle403Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem("refreshToken");
    return from(this.accountService.getNewToken(refreshToken)).pipe(
        switchMap(res => {
            if (res) {
                request = this._addToken(request, this.authService.getToken());
                return next.handle(request); // Don't perform the request intercepted 
            }
            return from(this.router.navigate(["/login"])).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY));
        }),
        catchError(() => from(this.router.navigate(["/login"])).pipe(switchMapTo(EMPTY)),
    );
}
```

Comment: Updated, I've build a stream instead of promises.

Comment: I use breakpoint inside if(res){..} and it is not reachable with the code above.

Comment: then you need to debug what `this.accountService.getNewToken(refreshToken)` returns.